# Airflow: check if first parent was skipped and fail the pipeline if it was

Tags: airflow

I am trying to learn airflow and have come up with a problem that I cannot see a solution for. I have a series of operators chained one after the other, and at some point I need to automatically check if the last operator was skipped or not (but only the last). And if it was skipped, I need the pipeline to have a state "failed".

I have come up with an operator that has to check status of its first parent operator, and fail if parent operator was skipped. Unfortunately I couldn't find a `trigger_rule` that checks for skipping events only in the first upstream operator. How do I deal with this and make a node check only the first parent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I am understanding your ask correctly you want the following pattern:

- last task of the chain skips => DAG fails
- last task of the chain succeeds => DAG succeeds
- last task of the chain fails => DAG succeeds

like in the screenshot below:

[image: grid view]

This can be done by pulling the state of a specific task in this case `last_task_of_the_chain` from the Airflow context.

Below the version of the DAG where the `last_task_of_the_chain` is skipped via an AirflowException.

```py
from pendulum import datetime
from airflow.exceptions import AirflowException, AirflowSkipException

from airflow.decorators import (
    dag,
    task,
)

SKIP_TASK_ID = "last_task_of_the_chain"

@dag(
    schedule=None,
    start_date=datetime(2023, 1, 1),
    catchup=False,
)
def example_dag_basic():
    
    @task
    def task_one():
        return 1
    
    @task(
        task_id=SKIP_TASK_ID
    )
    def task_two():
        raise AirflowSkipException
    
    @task(
        trigger_rule="all_done"
    )
    def fail_if_upstream_skipped(**context):
        dag_run = context.get("dag_run")
        task_instance_parent = dag_run.get_task_instance(task_id=SKIP_TASK_ID)
        if task_instance_parent.state == "skipped":
            raise AirflowException
        else:
            return "parent task not skipped"
            

    task_one() >> task_two() >> fail_if_upstream_skipped()


    
example_dag_basic()
```

Using this pattern you can create a last task in your DAG that fails/succeeds depending on all sorts of combinations of specific tasks in your DAG having ended with specific states.